# MongoDB time is in stored as a string, how to filter on the parameter?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

there is a data set where unfortunately time is not stored as datetime ISO format, but as a string, something like

```
{"time" : "2015-08-28 09:24:30"}
```

Is there a way to filter records based on this variable time?

Changing all data to timestamp is one of the right way, , but is there a way to do without it?

Comment: Not really any "sane" way. Changing this to a `Date` BSON object is trivial ( plenty of answers here ) presuming it is already UTC ( and a fairly minor change if it is not ) so why not just do it? It's going to save on storage as well since the internal store of a BSON `Date` is a lot less than a string of that length. But you can of course "do it" if your data is lexically ordered, as it appears to be. It's just not wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the "real" anwer here is "don't do it", as converting your "strings" to a "BSON date" is a very trival process. Best done in the mongodb shell as a "one off" operation:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.find({ "time": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "time": new Date( doc.time.replace(" ","T") ) }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Of course adjusting for "timezone" as required, but a fairly simple case anyway.

And then all "strings" are now BSON dates that you can query for a "day" for example with:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "time": { "$gte": new Date("2015-08-28"), "$lt": new Date("2015-08-29") }
})
```

And do so with relative ease, and no matter what your langauge is as long as the `Date` object passed in is supported for serialization via the driver.

But of course, as long as your strings are "lexical" ( which basically means "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" ) then you can actually use a "range" with  "string values" instead:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "time": { 
        "$gte": "2015-08-28 00:00:00", 
        "$lt": "2015-08-29 00:00:00"
    }
})
```

And it works, but it just is not "wise".

Change your "strings" to BSON Date. It takes less storage and there is no "mucking around" with working the data into a real "Date" for your language API when you actually need it as such. The work is already done.

Comment: I don't think adding 'T' instead of a space covers this issue